# Windows keeps restoring DigitCert root certificates

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I issued a SSL certificate trought DigiCert which we know is globally recognized and its Trusted Roots should be by default in Windows installations.

However on one of my client's machine there was no intermediate root CA which led to several problems. Hence I decided to include DigiCert certificates (taken from their website) into the installation package we are sending to our clients.

Of course I wanted to test it first on my local win server 2008 but I can't remove DigiCert roots from the machine! I keep removing them as Current User and Local Computer from both Trusted Root CAs and Intermediate CAs but as soon as I open (not install, just open!) the issued certificate file (to see it's details), instantly the removed CAs appear in the stores again (as current user).

Comment: They keep getting added because its handled by `Windows Update`.  Why don't you just tell the client they need to update their installation?

Comment: So in theory disabling windows update should prevent it from being restored? As for the client, tell me about it. I tried to explain politely that this is not our fault they have some weird CA store but my boss insists we should be prepared for it.

Comment: Try it.  But the root certificates are handled by Windows Update.  Which is also the reason a (very) recent update revoked certifcates issued by an India root CA.